# Generate javadoc for JavaScript in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, javadoc

I need to generate documentation for a JavaScript project, and I would like to do it with Javadoc.

Unhopefully, I have to do it on Visual Studio 2013, and it looks like there is nothing to help Javadoc comments blocks. I would like at least when I do this :
`/**` + `enter` To generate that :

```
/**
 *
 */
```

I've looked for plugins or similar questions, on Stackoverflow and on Microsoft website, but I only found plugins or solutions for Doxygen.

Do am I really looking for something that doesn't exist, or is there something that I missed ? (I hope so)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Visual Studio you could use [**DocStubsJs**](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0cb7304b-ad78-4283-ba2b-42804657fcdd), An extension for Visual Studio 2012+ to auto generate documentation comment stubs for JSDoc and VSDoc in JavaScript and TypeScript editors.

The source code available on [GitHub](https://github.com/mobermeyer/DocStubsJs)

Quote from GitHub README:

> DocStubsJs is a fairly straight-forward plugin that uses events and
>   string parsing to determine when and how to insert a document stub. It
>   essentially just watches key-strokes for the identifying documentation
>   comment bock initializers. ("///" for VSDoc, and "/**" for JSDoc) Once
>   it has determined that these have been entered on an empty line, then
>   it parses the lines surrounding it to determine whether to add a new
>   comment line, create a documentation comment stub, or do nothing.

Note:

For [**JSDoc**](http://usejsdoc.org/) comments, parameter tags will be added as well as a return tag after typing "/**" on the line above a function header. (Note for Web Essentials users: you may have to disable auto-completion of multi-line comments in the JavaScript options for Web Essentials in order for this to work.)